# X-!Snaps! not starting

Tags: ssh, 19.04, snap

I am connected to my Ubuntu Disco server via SSH (from Windows).

I am able to run X-Apps, for example, my LXPanel is showing up right now. I installed Firefox (via `apt`), it shows.

I installed several X-snaps, all of them display errors like the following:

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display localhost:10.0
```

The only one running is VS Code. This is a "classic" snap.

Does anybody have an idea for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, i tried again, and by now i found the answer myself. Obviously i was not able to google this in my first attempts...

The problem is the Xauthority, because this is not known by the snaps.
The issue is discussed [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/x11-forwarding-using-ssh/2381/14) with multiple solutions, including

```
XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority /snap/bin/mysnap
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ssh server authentication cookie pair would be mostly the problem

From **ssh**(8) man page:

> If the file ~/.ssh/rc exists, sh(1) runs it after reading the
>   environment files but before starting the user's shell or command. It
>   must not produce any output on stdout; stderr must be used instead. If
>   X11 forwarding is in use, it will receive the "proto cookie" pair in
>   its standard input (and DISPLAY in its environment). The script must
>   call xauth(1) because sshd will not run xauth automatically to add X11
>   cookies.

So you could add to /etc/ssh/sshrc the followin (also stated in manual):

```
if read proto cookie && [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    if [ 'echo $DISPLAY | cut -c1-10' = 'localhost:' ]; then
    # X11UseLocalhost=yes
    echo add unix:'echo $DISPLAY |
    cut -c11-' $proto $cookie
    else
    # X11UseLocalhost=no
    echo add $DISPLAY $proto $cookie
    fi | xauth -q - 
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as i wrote, i CAN raun x-apps, but not X-Snaps. Adding the file as given in the manpage doesn't change anything.

Comment: You could also link .Xauthority to snap directory, like you told in your resolving answer.

Comment: yes, but that is a single-user solution.