# only some apps work with X11 forwarding to XcXsrv from an Ubuntu 22.04 Virtualbox guest

Tags: putty, x11-forwarding

I have a Windows 10 host running Virtualbox with an Ubuntu 22.04 guest installed.  It uses NAT networking with port 22 forwarding to the guest.  I then have VcXsrv X Server v1.20.14.0 installed on another Windows 10 machine.  From there, I've setup Putty to permit X11 forwarding during an ssh session to the Ubuntu 22.04 guest on the other box.

What I am finding is that only some applications display.  xclock and gvim pop right up and behave as you'd expect.  shotwell and gedit don't display, but don't give any error messages either.  firefox doesn't display and complains about an unsupported authorization protocol.

```
Using username "user".
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-37-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 updates can be applied immediately.

Last login: Fri Jun 10 21:00:39 2022 from 10.0.2.2
user@ubuntu:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE x11
tty x11
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep X11
[sudo] password for user:
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
user@ubuntu:~$ xclock
user@ubuntu:~$ gvim
user@ubuntu:~$ gedit
^C
user@ubuntu:~$ firefox
PuTTYNG X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [X-!Snaps! not starting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181046/x-snaps-not-starting)

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with this for a couple hours today.

[X-!Snaps! not starting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181046/x-snaps-not-starting)

The above post thread links to the solution I used.
I don't fully understand the details, but the following line allowed me to run firefox successfully:

```
XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority /snap/bin/firefox
```

This also worked for other applications I was having issues with. Which is surprising, since I installed chromium and firefox via APT and not via snap. I reinstalled firefox and did notice that it mentions snap while installing.

I suppose snap doesn't know where XAUTHORITY is, and doing this tells it where it is. Don't quote me on that.