# Start ubuntu desktop over ssh

Tags: x11-forwarding

On Winows 11 I ave PuTTY and Xming. I want to run an Ubuntu desktop session in a window. (I'm sure I used to do this with Solaris.)
I can `ssh -Y` into Ubuntu and `xeyes` and `xclock` work.

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
$
```

However:

```
$ firefox
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gimp/2.0/help /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/xubuntu-docs /usr/share/xubuntu-docs none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
$
```

and

```
$ nautilus .
Nautilus-Share-Message: 11:16:20.428: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

and then it hangs.

Can this even work at all? What sort of thing could I try to get it to work?

**Update**

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ubuntu-desktop
ii  ubuntu-desktop                                1.481                                   amd64        The Ubuntu desktop system
ii  ubuntu-desktop-minimal                        1.481                                   amd64        The Ubuntu desktop minimal system
$
```

Comment: Are packages like `ubuntu-desktop` installed on your system.

Comment: Are you a system administrator of the server?  If so, you can look into installing `x2go` on the server, and the corresponding client on your own machine.

Comment: It's likely because firefox is installed as a snap - see [X-!Snaps! not starting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181046/x-snaps-not-starting)